# XNA animation inside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, xna, xna-4.0

My question is it possible to do play XNA animation inside WPF ? and how can I achieve this ?

I did little searching and found that it's possible with Winform but I need to do it in WPF as my whole project is in wpf and only this issue is what's left.

**Update**: 
Here's the source I'm using. 
https://xnamodelviewer.codeplex.com/

**Update 2**: 
I tried using a naive way which is putting the initialization of animationplayer & animationclips in the draw function and updating it in the update function which requires gameTime (not available) so I used instead a stopwatch to achieve the same thing but the model didn't do any animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after sometime tinkering with WPF and XNA and switched to another method illustrated here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/25/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application.aspx and still the animation didn't play (it removes hosting winform inside WPF) , So I've decided to switch to winform (no more wpf).